# Trying to upload pictures with Angular and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

What's the easiest/best way to upload images using Angular/Node setup? I'm currently trying Multer but I am having problems getting it to work correctly.

Nodejs:

```
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/'});
app.post('/api/entries', upload.single('file'), entryCtrl.addEntry);
```

This is some of the code I have in Angular:

```
this.addEntry = (uploadUrl, data) => {
  console.log('data', data);

  const fd = new FormData();

  for (var key in data) {
    fd.append(key, data[key]);
  }

  console.log('fd', fd);

  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
  });
}
```

My `console.log` for `data` is correct but when I use `FormData()` and loop through, `fd` is an empty object.

CTRL:

```
$scope.addEntry = () => {
  const uploadUrl = '/api/entries';
  return MainService.addEntry(uploadUrl, $scope.entry);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" name="file" file-model="entry.file">

    <input type="text" ng-model="entry.length">

    <button type="submit" ng-click="addEntry()">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<pre>
  {{ entry }}
</pre>
```

Here is the Directive I am using for this:

```
directive("fileModel", function($parse) {

   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
        const model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        const modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', () => {
          scope.$apply(() => {
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
    }
  }

});
```

The logs:

```
data Object {file: File, length: "12.52"}
file: FilelastModified: 1464152993000
lastModifiedDate: Wed May 25 2016 00:09:53 GMT-0500 (CDT)
name: "IMG_0022.JPG"
size: 569111type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: Filelength: "12.52"__proto__: Object
fd FormData {}
```

This is where my problem is. I get the file under `data.file` but when try to append it to `FormData()`, I get an empty object. Something is wrong with my binding.

Suggestions?

Comment: When you say that fd is an empty object - are you sure? `console.log(fd)` shows just `FormData {}` in the console for me too, no matter what is in the FormData object. Does it print the appended file if you write `for(var f of fd) console.log(f);` instead? What if you open the Network tab in dev tools? Does the file get sent?

Comment: @noppa it doesn't hit my endpoint because a pic is required in my Entry model and it isn't sending a pic. i can't figure out why it isn't binding when i select a file but it's logging it as being passed through to my service

Comment: And you are sure the file is not in the FormData object `fd`? The fact that `console.log('fd', fd)` prints "FormData {}" alone does not mean the file is not there.

Comment: @noppa So if its printing only "FormData {}" how should I know if the file is there or not?

Comment: What does `for(var f of fd) console.log(f);` print?

Comment: @noppa `F ["file", File]0: "file"1: FilelastModified: 1465321614000lastModifiedDate: Tue Jun 07 2016 12:46:54 GMT-0500 (CDT)name: "big-bass.jpg"size: 33177type: "image/jpeg"webkitRelativePath: ""`